# Calculation of Bit wise NOT

Tags: c

How to calculate `~a` manually? I am seeing these types of questions very often.

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
    unsigned int a = 10;
    a = ~a;
    printf("%d\n", a);
}
```

Comment: If using the `~` operator is not computing the desired result "manually", then what exactly do you mean by "manually"?

Answer (score 2):

> The result of the `~` operator is the bitwise complement of its (promoted) operand
>   C11dr §6.5.3.3

When used with `unsigned`, it is sufficient to mimic `~` with exclusive-or with `UINT_MAX` which is the same type and value as `(unsigned) -1`. [@EOF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38329286/calculation-of-bit-wise-not/38330807#comment64073032_38329323)

```
unsigned int a = 10;
// a = ~a;
a ^= -1;
```

Answer (score 1):

You could XOR it with a bitmask of all 1's.

```
unsigned int a = 10, mask = 0xFFFFFFFF;
a = a ^ mask;
```

This is assuming of course that an `int` is 32 bits.  That's why it makes more sense to just use `~`.

Comment: Why not `mask = -1;`?

Comment: @EOF That assumes 2's complement.  Attempting to assign a negative value to an unsigned variable is undefined behavior.

Comment: No. `mask` is `unsigned`, so pure binary representation. C11 draft standard n1570: *6.3.1.3 Signed and unsigned integers 2 Otherwise, if the new type is unsigned, the value is converted by repeatedly adding or
subtracting one more than the maximum value that can be represented in the new type
until the value is in the range of the new type.* This is not undefined in any way, shape or form.

Answer (score 0):

Just convert the number to binary form, and change '1' by '0' and '0' by '1'.

That is:

```
10 (decimal)
```

Converted to binary (32 bits as usual in an `int`) gives us:

```
0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 1010
```

Then apply the `~` operator:

```
1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 0101
```

Now you have a number that could be interpreted as an unsigned 32 bit number, or signed one. As you are using `%d` in your `printf` and `a` is an `int`, signed it is.

To find out the value in decimal from a signed (2-complement) number do as this:

- If the most significant bit (the leftmost) is 0, then just convert back the binary number to decimal as usual.
- if the most significant bit is 1 (our case here), then change '1' by '0' and '0' by '1', add '1' and convert to decimal prepending a minus sign to the result.

So it is:

```
1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 0101
^
|
Its most significant bit is 1, so first we change 0 and 1

0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 1010
```

And then, we add 1

```
0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 1010
                                      1
---------------------------------------
0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 1011
```

Take this number and convert back to decimal prepending a minus sign to the result. The converted value is 11. With the minus sign, is -11

Comment: Answer is -11 May I know how to do that !

Answer (score -1):

This function shows the binary representation of an int and swaps the 0's and 1's:

```
void not(unsigned int x)
{
    int i; 
    for(i=(sizeof(int)*8)-1; i>=0; i--)
        (x&(1u<<i))?putchar('0'):putchar('1');
    printf("\n");
}
```

Source: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitwise_operations_in_C#Right_shift_.3E.3E